# Android Adding Buttons to Toolbar Programmatically

Tags: java, android, alignment, toolbar

I am trying to create a toolbar programmatically and add left and right bar buttons without using XML.

But the button is not getting aligned to right.

```
Toolbar TopTulBarVar = new Toolbar(this);
TopTulBarVar.setId(View.generateViewId());
TopTulBarVar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
TopTulBarVar.setTitle("Ttl Txt");
TopTulBarVar.setSubtitle("Dtl Txt");

Button NamBarBtnVar = new Button(this);
NamBarBtnVar.setText("Select");
NamBarBtnVar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams NamBarBtnRulVar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
NamBarBtnRulVar.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
TopTulBarVar.addView(NamBarBtnVar, NamBarBtnRulVar);
```

Also tried

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RloRulVar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RloRulVar.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

I am getting as below image

[image]

But need like

[image]

Comment: can you add some screenshot for better understanding

Comment: Added Screenshots...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**In Activity code**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool);
    setSupportActionBar(t);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //left side button

    Button b = new Button(this);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams l1=new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    l1.gravity = Gravity.START;
    b.setLayoutParams(l1);
    b.setText("left");
    t.addView(b);

    //center Textview
    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Text:1");
    Toolbar.LayoutParams l2 = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    l2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    text.setLayoutParams(l2);
    t.addView(text);

    //Right side button

    Button b1=new Button(this);
    b1.setText("Right");
    Toolbar.LayoutParams l3=new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    l3.gravity=Gravity.END;
    b1.setLayoutParams(l3);
    t.addView(b1);

}
```

**Toolbar XML code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:id="@+id/tool"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Can u modify so we build Toolbar also in Java code instead of XML.
I dont want anything in XML as I want to reuse this code again and again.

Comment: Also consider voting my question too

Comment: Looks like no way of adding toolbar dynamically I tried but didn't workout (i will edit my answer in future if I found a way)

Comment: This can also be used with MaterialButton class buttons.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this nowadays: please make sure to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.LayoutParams` while adding view programmatically as for me just typing `Toolbar.LayoutParams` were accidentally resolved to `android.widget.Toolbar.LayoutParams` by Android Studio. I spent some time trying to figure out why gravity is not changed: no exception occures if set wrond layoutParams before adding a view to the toolbar. I have `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in my layout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

for me I added one switch button in `Toolbar` and it does work :

```
            <Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    style="@style/Toolbar"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/btn_accessible"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
                        android:paddingRight="25sp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb"
                        android:track="@drawable/custom_switch_track"

                />


            </Toolbar>
```

and in activity i just set `onClick` listener

Comment: this is exactly the thing that the OP specifically said he did NOT want to do